# Pattern-match on type in order to implement equality for existentially typed constructor in Coq

Tags: coq

Let's say I have again a small problem with my datatype with an existential quantified component. This time I want to define when two values of type `ext` are equal.

```coq
Inductive ext (A: Set) :=
| ext_ : forall (X: Set), option X -> ext A.

Fail Definition ext_eq (A: Set) (x y: ext A) : Prop :=
  match x with
  | ext_ _ ox => match y with
                 | ext_ _ oy => (* only when they have the same types *)
                                ox = oy
                 end
  end.
```

What I'd like to do is somehow distinguish between the cases where the existential type is actually same and where it's not. Is this a case for JMeq or is there some other way to accomplish such a case distinction?

I googled a lot, but unfortunately I mostly stumbled upon posts about dependent pattern matching.

I also tried to generate a (boolean) scheme with `Scheme Equality for ext`, but this wasn't successful because of the type argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is somehow distinguish between the cases where the existential type is actually same and where it's not.

This is not possible as Coq's logic is compatible with the univalence axiom which says that isomorphic types are equal. So even though `(unit * unit)` and `unit` are syntactically distinct, they cannot be distinguished by Coq's logic.

A possible work-around is to have a datatype of codes for the types you are interested in and store that as an existential. Something like this:

```
Inductive Code : Type :=
  | Nat : Code
  | List : Code -> Code.

Fixpoint meaning (c : Code) := match c with
  | Nat     => nat
  | List c' => list (meaning c')
end.

Inductive ext (A: Set) :=
  | ext_ : forall (c: Code), option (meaning c) -> ext A.

Lemma Code_eq_dec : forall (c d : Code), { c = d } + { c <> d }.
Proof.
intros c; induction c; intros d; destruct d.
- left ; reflexivity.
- right ; inversion 1.
- right ; inversion 1.
- destruct (IHc d).
  + left ; congruence.
  + right; inversion 1; contradiction.
Defined.

Definition ext_eq (A: Set) (x y: ext A) : Prop.
refine(
  match x with | @ext_ _ c ox =>
  match y with | @ext_ _ d oy =>
  match Code_eq_dec c d with
   | left eq   => _
   | right neq => False
  end end end).
subst; exact (ox = oy).
Defined.
```

However this obviously limits quite a lot the sort of types you can pack in an `ext`. Other, more powerful, languages (e.g. equipped with [Induction-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction-recursion)) would give you more expressive power.

Comment: Nice workaround! Let me add a couple comments: (1) `Code_eq_dec` can be *literally* defined using the `decide equality` tactic, which will really shine when we start adding more data constructors into `Code`; (2) `ext_` can be destructed using the `let` expression (since it has only one constructor), which makes the code a bit more concise: `let (c,ox) := x in ...`

Comment: Ah, thanks! I couldn't remember the name of that `decide equality` tactic, tried various combinations of keywords I had in mind and finally gave up. Nice to know that `let` can break down any single-constructor datatype too.

Comment: I just want to add that, unfortunately, this workaround is too limiting for my setting, but your answer and the comments were helpful after all.